# Django Reset API not working on Docker

Tags: django, api, docker, django-rest-framework

I am new to `Docker`, before docker I work on `heroku`, and these `Django Rest APIs` run perfectly on local server and heroku, but when i deploy these APIs on docker they sending me `400 Bad Request` error, I don't know what the issue is, can somebody give me a hint what went wrong on docker.

For docker image :

```
sudo docker build -t brainplow/reviewsaidev .
```

For Image run :

```
sudo docker run -p 8888:8000 -d brainplow/reviewsaidev
```

To push Image :

```
sudo docker push brainplow/reviewsaidev
```

I don't know how to see error log on docker.

Here is Error log

```
(ven_reviews_ai) nazir@nazir-HP-EliteBook-840-G1 ~/PycharmProjects/ReviewsAI $ sudo docker run -p 9009:8000  brainplow/reviewsaidev
Starting Gunicorn.
[2017-10-30 09:00:06 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-10-30 09:00:06 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2017-10-30 09:00:06 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-10-30 09:00:06 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2017-10-30 09:00:06 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2017-10-30 09:00:06 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2017-10-30 09:00:54,733 : INFO : loading Word2Vec object from trained_models/laptop2
2017-10-30 09:00:55,695 : INFO : loading wv recursively from trained_models/laptop2.wv.* with mmap=None
2017-10-30 09:00:55,695 : INFO : setting ignored attribute syn0norm to None
2017-10-30 09:00:55,696 : INFO : setting ignored attribute cum_table to None
2017-10-30 09:00:55,696 : INFO : loaded trained_models/laptop2
Internal Server Error: /func/demo/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 706, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 664, in get_context
    'content': self.get_content(renderer, data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 411, in get_content
    content = renderer.render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 105, in render
    separators=separators
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 437, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 70, in default
    return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'LookupError' is not JSON serializable
2017-10-30 09:00:58,817 : ERROR : Internal Server Error: /func/demo/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 706, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 664, in get_context
    'content': self.get_content(renderer, data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 411, in get_content
    content = renderer.render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 105, in render
    separators=separators
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 404, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 437, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 70, in default
    return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'LookupError' is not JSON serializable
[2017-10-30 09:01:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, You need to provide more information so we can help you, imagine you are answering this question, what extra information could be helpful? like how did you create docker image, how did you start the container, Can you interact with your rest api inside your container, Do you have error logs from your app?

Comment: there is no error on heroku and on local server, but i don't know about what issue is on docker.

Comment: If there's any message coming along with the `400` code read it - it may contain some hints.

Comment: @Opal I add the error log but I don't know why error is occurring on docker image.

Comment: The traceback shows that this is an error in the python code. So I'm not sure it's directly caused by running the app in docker. Can you post the view and serializer classes you are using? Seems that you are trying to serialize an Exception.

Comment: Can you also add the view attached to `/func/demo/` and the serializers used?